# Is definite integral of monotonic odd function always positive?

Tags: definite-integrals, control-theory, even-and-odd-functions

I wish to prove an identity in control theory which uses the assertion that, integral of a monotonic odd mapping is always positive definite.

For instance consider an example below: 
\begin{equation}
C(u)=\int_0^u\phi^{-1}(v)dv
\end{equation}
In expression above, $\phi^{-1}=\tanh^{-1}$ is odd function and the limit $u$ can be both positive or a negative number. 
Certain points to be noted are:
(i) $\phi(.)$ is bounded and
(ii) Its first derivative is also bounded.
(iii) $\phi$ belongs to $L_2(\Omega)$ i.e its Lebesgue integral should be finite.

Please help me prove this assertion! Thanks a lot for your time and consideration.

Comment: The assertion may be assuming (or leaving unstated) that the function is montonically *increasing*.

Comment: I have modified my question and have added the remaining bits, the inverse mapping of the integrand should be bounded and smooth and it should belong to $L_2(\Omega)$.

Comment: In the linked reference it is assumed that $\phi$ approximates a control saturation. As such, it is implicitly assumed that $\phi$ is monotonically increasing, as saturation is a monotonically increasing function. And then of course $C(u)$ is positive definite, like suggested by @eyeballfrog. Without that implicit assumption, the statement is wrong as shown by the answer of Kavi Rama Murthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\phi^{-1}$ is odd and monotonically increasing, it holds true that $\phi^{-1}(\theta u)\theta u\geq 0$ for all $\theta,u\in\mathbb{R}$ which in turn yields that $\phi^{-1}(\theta u) u\geq 0$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta\in[0,1]$.

Thus if we consider a change of variables $v=\theta u$ in the calculation of the integral $C(u)$ then we have that
$$C(u)=\int_0^u{\phi^{-1}(v)dv}=\int_0^{1}{\phi^{-1}(\theta u) u\: d\theta}\geq 0$$
Also, if $C(u)=0$ then $u=0$. A contradiction argument can be used to prove this. Assume therefore that $u\neq 0$. From  $C(u)=0$ we have that $\phi^{-1}(\theta u) u=0$ for a.e. $\theta\in[0,1]$ or equivalently $\phi^{-1}(\theta u)=0$ for a.e. $\theta\in[0,1]$ since $u\neq 0$. However, this implies $u=0$ due to monotonicity of $\phi^{-1}$ .

Thus $C(u)$ is indeed a positive definite function.

Comment: But you still need $\phi$ to be monotonically *increasing*, which was the actual point. Take $\phi = -\tanh$, so that $\phi^{-1} = -\tanh^{-1}$. Then evaluating $C(u)$ at $u = 1/2$ we get $C(1/2) = \log(2) - 3 \log(3)/4 \approx -0.13081 < 0$ so $C$ cannot be positive definite.

Comment: @SampleTime Well, having an increasing function is not a neccesary condition. What you need is $\phi^{-1}(x)x\geq 0$ for all $x$ which of course holds true for an increasing odd function such as $tanh(x)$. But also a sector nonlinearity in $[0,\infty)$ will do the trick.

Comment: True. Unfortunatly, the reference linked in the question (and the references cited in it) are not very precise about those differences.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a monotonic odd function so is $-f$. Hence the assertion is wrong.

Comment: I have modified my question, please have a look again.

Comment: With standard definitions in Mathematcis if $f$ satisfies your hypothesis so does $-f$. Can  you tell me which part of the hypothesis fails for $-f$? BTW $C(u)$ (as  a function of $u$) is the indefinite integral of $\phi^{-1}$ not the definite integral. A definite integral is just a  number.

Comment: Also positive and positive definite have different meanings. I think the question needs thorough revision.